# How to install Emacs (Text editor) on ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, emacs

I have tried to install emacs from source that I downloaded from the internet.

For that first I have chosen a path like:

`/home/anand/emac/emac-23.1` (where emac-23.1 is the extracted file)

Then I make it run like follows:

```
root@anand:/home/anand/softwares/emac/emacs-23.1# ./configure
```

But it displays:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I also tried another way:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

But it displays:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package emacs
```

All the above was done under an Admin Login, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Ubuntu linux comes without a lot of the things needed to compile programs. I think gnibbler's answer is correct, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install emacs   you missed the s off the end!

Comment: Try running "sudo apt-cache search emacs", this should show you all packages which might have something to do with emacs.

Comment: Also see [Minimal emacs24 installation on ubuntu](http://superuser.com/q/617468). It provides instructions for downloading and building Emacs 24.5 from sources that is about 25 MB in size. Its a 4x improvement over a standard ***`emacs-nox`*** package install from Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

`$ sudo apt-get install build-essential`
`$ sudo apt-get build-dep emacs`

Will help you download all the dependencies

My ubuntu has emacs22, if that will work for you

`$ sudo apt-get install emacs`  <==note you missed the s on the end when you tried before

Comment: Does this work for Emacs 23.1?

Comment: This will get the dependancies. However, you'll also need a build system installed, which you can get with the following:

sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: @Kinopiko: Try it. The repositories are usually kept relatively up to date, and the dependencies of software don't actually change that frequently.

Answer (score 4):

> sudo apt-get install emac

You have the package name wrong. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

Comment: after using this same problem .. 
sudo apt-get install emacs 

actually i missed that s when i was copying this errors to notepad
but first only i am using the above command...

Answer (score 4):

Are you using this in the shell or gnome?

try emacs snapshot for a better UI that looks like something which was not made in the 1990s

```
sudo apt-get install -y emacs-snapshot emacs-snapshot-el
```

and to launch it from without a windowing system

```
emacs -nw /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo aptitude install emacs23

Answer (score -1):

When connected to the internet, execute: `sudo apt-get emacs`