# How do I upgrade Emacs to the current version on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, emacs

I'm an Ubuntu Linux user looking to upgrade my Emacs from version 23.1.1 to the current version (23.3 I think). I have tried all of the suggested methods of upgrading on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/55642/how-to-install-emacs-text-editor-on-ubuntu-linux), but none of them work.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: My version of Ubuntu is Lucid Lynx

Answer (score 5):

I build the emacs from repo. I use git mirror to keep the local
copy. (one day older than the official bzr repo)

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
sudo sudo apt-get build-dep emacs

git clone git://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs
cd emacs
./autogen.sh &> log.autogen
./configure &> log.configure
make bootstrap &> log.bootstrap
sudo make install &> log.install
```

once in while i do `git pull` to catch up the repo & build again.

Comment: Just a correction - you'd do `git pull` to update to the newest version.